# Proper way of defining classes in css

Tags: html, css, class

I was wondering while defining classes in css, do I have to write the parent class as well?

For example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

I know it works if I just do this.

```
.child{
    //properties
 }
```

But is there like a good practice or something to write like this,

```
.parent .child{
    //properties
}
```

Comment: You need not. But if there is child in another parent container and you want to specifically style this one, then you need to. You can also use .parent to override the properties of child because of specificity.

Comment: How to architect a CSS selector scheme is largely a matter of opinion and has been written about extensively. See [SMACSS](https://smacss.com), [OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki), [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/), etc. That said, this topic isn't really a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't, unless you need to.

---

**1.** Defining it with parent class will make it more specific. Consider this scenario, `.child` selector will apply to all elements which have it:

```css
.child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  Hi
</div>
```

**2.**  Now when you make it more specific, `.parent .child`, it will only apply to elements which have the class `.child` and `.parent` on parent element.

```css
.parent .child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  Hi
</div>
```